# Handling inputs from multiple elements on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I need to find a way to effectively handle button clicks on my Django webpage. Currently I have each button assigned a unique id, and I call JS function to handle the clicks:

```
< button id="id1_element1" onclick="bhandler(this.id)" />
```

Then in jQuery I analyze which button fired off the bhandler and take appropriate action on server side with ajax call.
The problem with this approach is that I have a lot of elements, and each event has a lot of ids. It would be cumbersome to name each button manually and then handle that  input in JS.

Is there an effective way to tackle this problem without writing a lot of manual code? Is jquery/ajax even the right tool? There seems to be so many JS frameworks these days, that I feel like there should be a one line solver for this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, writing event handler in element is a bad practice. You should write your event handler in javascript file.

Second, if you want to have one handler for multiple elements you can use class selector instead of ID. Note: I'm using native javascript for this demo.

Now after you select all the elements, use **if else** statement if you want to select specific element out of those elements. In this demo, i'm using **classList contains** method to determine whether my element has a specific class, then execute the function inside the if statement.

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

// loop blocks nodelist
blocks.forEach(function(block){
 
  // event listener
  block.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // if this element has element-1 class
    if(this.classList.contains("element-1")){
     alert("hey, i'm element 1");
    }
    
    // if this element has element-2 class
    if(this.classList.contains("element-2")){
     alert("hey, i'm element 2");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="block element-1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="block element-2">Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also,  wanted to add to the answer that it might be easier to use jQuery's $(".block").on("click", function() { ... });callback to avoid javascript loops.